# "elif" statement not working and throwing an error - python

Tags: python, list

I am a newcomer to python and tried to do something silly in visual code. One day I wrote this 220 lines of code. And now I am done writing it and I saw the following error:

```
List expression not allowed in type annotation . Use List[T] instead
```

I am kinda stuck in this because of this line:

```
elif: gender in ['F', 'f', 'female', 'Female']
```

The above line is the line that causes the error, but I copied the below code from an existing line, but this gives no error:

`if gender in ['m', 'M', 'Male', 'male']:`

Comment: shouldn't this `elif: gender in ['F', 'f', 'female', 'Female']` be `elif gender in ['F', 'f', 'female', 'Female']:`?

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra colon `:` after the `elif`, so instead of:

```
elif: gender in ['F', 'f', 'female', 'Female']
```

Try putting the colon in the end:

```
elif gender in ['F', 'f', 'female', 'Female']:
```

Then it will work.